# How to migrate Managed Metadata Store?

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013, taxonomy

I need to migrate Managed Metadata Store from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013 environment. What are the check-list, I need to prepare or what are the point I need to remember/cater or what I need to ask my client before migration of Managed Metadata Store from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013 (as I know the direct migration is not possible from 2007 to 2013)?

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: What is your current check-list?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have Managed Metadata Store in SharePoint 2007? Because it was introduced only in SharePoint 2010. Maybe it is some kind of 3rd party solution?